# Linux: rename file/dir in it's current location w/o changing pwd to that location?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

At the command line, lets say my `pwd` is something like:

```
/home/whatever
```

And there is a file in some deep directory that I want to rename. Normally I would do this:

```
# mv /var/some/deep/folder/structure/fileA /var/some/deep/folder/structure/fileB
```

What question is, are there any command line tricks to rename a file/dir without having to type out the entire directory structure again?  Something like:

```
# mv /var/some/deep/folder/structure/fileA fileB
```

The problem with that command is that it moves fileA to your `pwd`. Obviously I want to keep it in the same location and simply rename it. So as I said, are there any tricks to achieve this without having to type out the entire directory structure again? It's simply a question out of curiosity and laziness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on your shell. In zsh you can:

```
mv /var/some/deep/folder/structure/{fileA,fileB}
```

If you're using bash, consider migrating to zsh - it's a pretty straightforward process and I'm sure you'll love zsh. :)

**Edit**:

It seems to work in bash, see Lunar_Lamp's comment.

Comment: I use this quite often in Bash, but I forgot to suggest that in my answer!

Comment: Wow, it works in bash too, I didn't knew it :)

Answer (score 4):

### There are at least three tricks to eliminate the repetitive typing.

… and they all work in the Bourne-Again shell, the Korn shell, and the Z shell.

- Use shell variables:

  ```
  dir=/var/some/deep/folder/structure
  mv "${dir}"/fileA mv "${dir}"/fileB
  ```
- Use brace expansion:

  ```
  mv /var/some/deep/folder/structure/{fileA,fileB}
  ```
- Use a subshell:

  ```
  (cd /var/some/deep/folder/structure/ && mv fileA fileB)
  ```

Other typing-reduction tricks include more shell-specific tricks such as functions and aliases, and shell-neutral tricks such as *using your terminal emulator's copy and paste facilities*.  ☺

Answer (score 1):

While there may be more efficient shortcuts, these would be the two methods I'd use frequently:

```
aa=/var/some/deep/folder/structure/
mv "$aa"fileA "$aa"fileB
```

Or

```
cd /var/some/deep/folder/structure
mv fileA fileB
cd -
```

Now, obviously they're not the efficient solutions that you're after, but they can both (in my opinion) be quicker than typing out the full path each time.